# Sqlite in iOS 'database is locked' error

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, insert

I am using sqlite db for my iOS app. Here i get an error saying 'database is locked' while I am trying to insert a row in a table. I agree there are many questions posted for the same and many solutions and reasons given for the error but mine is not solved with any of those.
Reasons being multithreading in sqlite is prohibited, database should be open, finalize should be called etc. I am posting my code to make it more transparent.

**Insert Function**

```
 int open=sqlite3_open([@"/Users/macintosh/Documents/Apps/Project/MyLocal DB/MyLocal.sqlite" UTF8String], &database);

sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;

const char *sql = "insert into History (MNo,PID, Move,Result,WID, CreatedOn) Values( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];


if(open==SQLITE_OK)
{

    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) ==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 0, mid);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, pid);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, cno);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 3, result);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 4, wid);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [[DateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);



        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"inserted the values in table");

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@" not inserted the values in table");
            NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);



    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSLog(@"db closed");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

Note: I have used same function at many places to insert a row and it works well. I got this error now and I have made sure there is no other statement running on the same database while this statement is being run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to close this database in any where that's why you are receiving this error

Comment: Ok I agree on this answer hence i have kept NSLog below each open and close db statement, i then changed its location and moved it to another writable location (it was previously also located to writable location).i restarted my Mac but I am still there. it still shows locked. I have checked my NSLog statements, DB is nowhere left open Divz. Thanx

Comment: Hey hi, i just found my error. In one of the functions i was returning from db without calling finalize and close statement..thanx for help

Answer (score 2):

Often when you get this kind of error you have parallell processes in your app trying to access the same database at the same time. If that's the case, try to put:

```
sqlite3_busy_timeout(database, 500);
```

somewhere between `sqlite3_open` and `sqlite3_prepare` in your code.

Then the database-connection will try to read/write in 500 milliseconds before it gives up, which is usually enough time to escape the locking.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons for this:

1. You may have forgotten to close database after query execution. You need to close database after every execution.
2. You may be executing multiple queries simultaneously. In case you execute multiple queries simultaneously, you must put some delay between multiple query executions.

Comment: You may be executing multiple queries simultaneously. In case you execute multiple queries simultaneously, you must put some delay between multiple query executions. how to add delay between two query